# select multiple columns from multiple tables based on a specif value

Tags: mysql, database

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEFgQ.jpg)

Hi, How can i select diferent values on this tables to get a report like this:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">MATERIALES.COD_MATERIAL</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">MATERIALES.CANTIDAD_NECESARIA</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">RQ.ID</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">OC.ID_OC</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">ENTRADA.ID_EA</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">SALIDA.ID_SA</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">material code # 1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">needed amount for material 1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">RQ001</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">OC001</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">amount that arrived for material # 1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">amount that was shipped for material # 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">material code # 2<br></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">needed amount for material 2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">RQ001</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">OC001</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">amount that arrived for material # 1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">amount that was shipped for material # 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've been trying around diferent sql queries but i'm very rusty at it at the moment.

Comment: Your formatting is totally unclear.  Please edit your question and include information needed to get you an answer.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please tell us.

Comment: I have tried this: `SELECT MATERIALES.COD_MATERIAL AS MATERIAL, MATERIALES.CANTIDAD_NECESARIA, RQ.Id AS RQ, OC.ID_OC AS OC, OC.CONSECUTIVO AS C, ENTRADA.ID_EA AS EA, SALIDA.ID_SA AS SA
FROM RQ, OC, ENTRADA, SALIDA, MATERIALES
WHERE MATERIALES.OM='30003510'
GROUP BY MATERIALES.COD_MATERIAL, RQ.ID, OC.ID_OC, OC.CONSECUTIVO, ENTRADA.ID_EA, SALIDA.ID_SA, MATERIALES.CANTIDAD_NECESARIA;`
 but it gives me duplicated results